# How can i make an application using Node.js, which can separate all the files with same extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

[image]

***How to write code in node.JS in which we select a directory and the code automatically separates all the files of that selected directory with the same extension and put then in a separate folder.***

Comment: Check Node fs module (File System)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. Using `fs` module and `path` module

Which will first check the extension and rename file (move) to new folder.

You can make changes accordingly. Use `if`

```js
const testFolder = './';
const fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')

var oldPath = 'old/path/file.txt'
var newPath = 'new/path/file.txt'

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        const ext = path.extname(file);
        fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
        })
    });
});
```